# Ensuring that variable substituion in SQLite from Tcl will always be of the desired type?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

What is the proper way to ensure that Tcl variables are treated as the correct type in SQLite?

This active session appears to be about the simplest scenario possible in setting `number` to `50` but it appears SQLite treats `:number` as a string, `:number+0` and `$number` as an number.

If, instead, use `incr nbr 50` then SQLite treats `:nbr` as a number.

Is there a way to "declare" the variable in Tcl such that SQLite will treat it as desired; or should every value be cast in the SQL expression?

I'd like to know how to make sure queries will always work as desired rather than just using `cast` on variables that "fail" to be recognized as desired while testing; and I've yet to recognize some pattern or best practice.

If all variable substitution is not treated as string and cast to a number in the SQL (except when testing reveals an issue), could a future SQLite version result in an instance in which it "just works" changing to the need to cast?

Thank you.

```
% package require sqlite3
3.43.2
% sqlite3 db
% set number 50
50
% db eval {select min(300, :number)}
300
% db eval {select min(300,:number+0)}
50
% db eval "select min(300,$number)"   
50
% db eval {select min(300, cast(:number as integer))}
50
% incr nbr 50
50
% db eval {select min(300,:nbr)}
50
% db eval "select min(300,$nbr)"
50

% db eval {create table numbers (id integer, value integer);
 insert into numbers values (1,300);}
% db eval {select min(value,:number) from numbers;} 
300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, if you run the value through `expr` then it gets a numeric interpretation by SQLite, but you need to be a *little* careful to stop Tcl from just factoring the value out as a literal when testing:

```
set number 50
set number [expr {$number}]
db eval {select min(300, :number)}
```

This tends not to be a big problem when doing more production-oriented code as you put constants in the SQL code and only parameterise values that change (and those will quite possibly have a numeric nature anyway).

If you're really worried about it, put a `CAST` in your SQL.

---

At the bytecode level, the `expr` becomes sending the value through an operation called `tryCvtToNumeric` which gives values a numeric interpretation if they can have one. Literals default to having no interpretation. Formally, we prefer C code to not depend on the existing interpretations of values, but rather to just ask for the one they want, but the tclsqlite extension (called that to distinguish it from the underlying library) doesn't do that and never has.

It's more important when dealing with `BLOB` data. That's when you use `@var` instead of `:var`...

Comment: Sniffing on Tcl's changeable internal value representation is a questionable design decision by SQLite. Personally, I would always be explicit and use `CAST`.

Comment: Thank you. If all variables written via `INSERT` and '`UPDATE` queries are `CAST` (or strict tables used),  when performing a comparison that could be used on numeric or string values (which I assume is just about all of them), should a database column ever be `CAST` also or only the Tcl variables?

Answer (score 1):

sqlite as far as I recall snoops on the objtype of the Tcl values it receives, and changes its behaviour based on that, which I feel is an abuse of the system, or at least a misunderstanding of it.  That "type" is really just a cached value reflecting what it was last treated as, and really doesn't mean anything about what that value *is* (like in a database type sense).  That said, sqlite itself treats database types more as guidelines than rules and will happily store things other than what the column is declared as, so it should mostly work out ok, if you squint just right.

Your example demonstrates why snooping on the last used objtype isn't a valid strategy:

```
set number 50
puts "at this stage, number's objtype is: [tcl::unsupported::representation $number]"
# Programmer likely thinks of $number as containing a number,
# but it's actually a string

set number [expr {$number}]
puts "after coercion by expr: [tcl::unsupported::representation $number]"
# Now it's been used as a number, and has an integer objtype

puts "digits in number: [string length $number]"
# Programmer still thinks it's a number, but now it's a string again:
puts "after string length: [tcl::unsupported::representation $number]"

# And, just for fun, let's view it as a list:
puts "llength: [llength $number]"
# now it's a list:
puts "after llength: [tcl::unsupported::representation $number]"
```

outputs:

```
at this stage, number's objtype is: value is a pure string with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0xffffffffdba1d820, string representation "50"
after coercion by expr: value is a int with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0xffffffffdba1e270, internal representation 0x32:0x0, no string representation
digits in number: 2
after string length: value is a utf32string with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0xffffffffdba1e270, internal representation 0xffffffffdba505b0:0x0, string representation "50"
llength: 1
after llength: value is a list with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0xffffffffdba1e270, internal representation 0xffffffffdba48c10:0x0, string representation "50"
```

I've had so many discussions over the years with people who can't accept the idea that Tcl values really, *really* don't have formal types other than string and insist on pretending that they do, and every case has this issue.

Going further, work has been slowly progressing to allow Tcl values to have *more than one* cached objtype (tip 445 hides the internal details that implement the objtype associated with a value, so that it can be changed to support this idea).  Some years ago I produced an experiment that implemented this idea using that TIP (usually called a "Hydra" - a many-headed Tcl value system), so I have concrete proof that it works and performs correctly.  This is largely to address a performance problem where a value is repeatedly used with two or more interpretations back and forth in quick succession, referred to as "shimmering" (although I've started to see people use that term to just refer to the obtype changing, even once.  I use "converted" for that).  Under a Hydra value model, the above code would accumulate all of the objtypes that it has been referred to, making subsequent accesses as any of those objtypes quick.  It should be clear that the approach of pretending Tcl values have types by snooping on objtype completely falls apart in a Hydra world.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and example. I didn't know it was so easy to query the information about reprsentation in Tcl. From your example, I think the reason that SQLite treats my integers as string is that I never do anything with them in Tcl other than first declare them or extract them from an in-coming request or another database table, such that they are pure string representation.

Comment: Perhaps, it could work with a Hydra set up when column/class affinity has a chance to work, for SQLite could select from Hydra the type that fits without recasting it. My examples, except the very last one, are sort of unfair in that there is no information given to SQLite to determine affinity.  But it would be nice if the `min()` function applied affinity like the comparison operators do; then the `:`-substitued variabe would have been cast to the column's data class rather its most recent Tcl representation. At least that is what it appears to be doing.

Comment: Yes, the correct thing to do is for the c code (sqlite here) to ask for a particular type from the Tcl value, informed by the class / column affinity / etc.  The handler for that type will then return that cached internal rep if it already has one for that value, or attempt to generate a new one from the value's string rep (or other type's existing intrep).  That way the type is supplied by the code asking for the value, and is agnostic about whether it's living in a hydra world or not, and is not subject to the hysteresis of state based on previous uses of that value.